# Python integer concatenation

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

How to concate integer and string with a forward slash(/) without space as given below

```
i am trying to get such output 
x=1
y=2
c=3
output without space 1/2/3

# Also in case if

x=1
b=2
c="a"

output : 1/2/a
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Comment: What should the output be ? If a string e.g. for just printing: `output=str(x)+str(y)+str(c)`

Comment: i am get such out put  1,'/',1,'/' but i need 1/1/1

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks  @JonnyTischbein it worked

Comment: @Goe that's a forward slash, not a back slash

Comment: You can also try: `output = "/".join(list(map(str,[x,y,c])))`, in case you have more variables.

Comment: Are you trying to create a file path? Use `os.path.join`. In general, it's better to write code that makes it as explicit as possible what you are *trying* to do, even if it's a little longer than code that makes implicit assumptions (like "`/` is the path separator."). `os.path.join(str(x), str(y), str(c))`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.format()`
i.e.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

out = "{}/{}/{}".format(a,b,c)
print(out)
```

For backslashes `\` use:

```
out = "{}\\{}\\{}".format(a,b,c)
```

as the backslash needs to be escaped

Comment: OP wants forward slashes, not backslashes

Comment: Look at the output, it contains forward slashes, not back slashes

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve your goal in Python, here are some i usually use:

```
x=1
y=2
z=3

output1 = '%s/%s/%s' % (x, y, z)
output2 = '{}/{}/{}'.format(x, y, z)
```

Because of readability, I think the best one is this:

```
output3 = '{a}/{b}/{c}'.format(a=x, b=y, c=c)
```

For more informations take a look at
https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, you can use the `sep` keyword argument to make `print` have this behaviour

```
print(1, 2, "a", sep="/")
# 1/2/a
```